# remove whole line inducing its line break from a file

Tags: bash

file example:

```
1 example
2 example
3 example
4 example
```

How to transform to get rid of `2 example` including its line break?

Desired result:

```
1 example
3 example
4 example
```

Comment: How do you decide what line to remove? The second line? The line that starts with `2` (or with `2 example`)? The line that contains exactly `2 example`? There are myriads of criteria to identify the line(s) to remove and even more ways to remove them. The question is not specific enough.

Comment: `printf '%s\n' '/^2 example/d' ,p w | ed -s file.txt` and you're done.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a job for grep...

```
#cat example.txt 
1 example
2 example
3 example
4 example 
#grep -o -E "^[13-4].*$" example.txt 
1 example
3 example
4 example
#grep -o -E "^[134].*$" example.txt > newfile.txt
#cat newfile.txt 
1 example
3 example
4 example
```

The regular expression:
`^` = Start of line
`[134]` = Number 1, 3 and 4 only
`.*` = All the rest
`$` = End of line

Comment: Try using `grep -v`. It's easier.

Comment: Or this: ```head -n1 example.txt >newfile.txt && tail -n2 example.txt >>newfile.txt```

Answer (score 0):

Bare bash:

```
while IFS= read -r line                 # read file line by line
do 
  ! [[ $line =~ ^2 ]] && echo "$line"   # do not print lines starting with 2
done < file > tmp                       # output to tmp
mv tmp file                             # replace file with tmp
```

Condition to pick line not to print is to choose lines not starting with char `2`. You might want to specify a better condition.

Using awk, you'd:

```
$ awk '/^[^2]/' file                    # > tmp && mv tmp file
```